# I have 2 internal HDD that were partitioned into a single logical drive how to remount

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I lost my PC over the weekend, but I recovered both disks, they are both fine, but due to the way they were partitioned together into a single drive I am unable to access them anymore via Windows and when I attempt to mount them one at a time in Linux I get the error:

```
The device '/dev/sdg1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
```

How can I mount them together?

Comment: What do you mean by "together"? Dynamic disks? RAID? Duct tape?

Comment: Dynamic disks (spanned volume in windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming the volume isn't broken just remount using diskpart.

[image: screenshot of steps and result]

1. In Windows open the command prompt, and type `diskpart`.
2. In DiskPart type `list volume`.
3. In diskpart type `select volume #`. Replace `#` with the spanned volume number.
4. In diskpart type `assign letter=b`. Replace `b` with the letter you want it to be mounted to.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer, because It will probably help someone in the future, but it looks like my MFT was corrupted from the power failure. I'm running Piriform Recuva now to try and pull off some personal stuff that wasn't backed up with all my work stuff.